# How to Clone Models in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, clone

I have a model which can be edited by a certain view; however, at the bottom of the view the user should get an option to save or discard all changes. This means that you will need to store a list of all the changes to be made to the model and then make those changes only once the 'save' button has been clicked. This sounds unnecessarily complicated and I have come up with an idea of an alternative approach which is to create a clone of the model and make changes to that in the view. Then if the user clicks 'save' delete the old model and replace it in its collection with the new one, otherwise you discard the cloned model.

This this an acceptable approach, and if so, how can I implement the cloning process?

This would be equivalent to fetching the data from the server again (but an extra HTTP request seems unnecessary).

Comment: But why would you need to clone the model at all? Anyways you can extract all values on Save click and save them; or else if you want to know if any of the values was changed while saving, just implement `Model View Binding`..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the [`clone`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clone) method. Short example below:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.realModel = this.model;
        this.model = this.realModel.clone();
    },
    onSave: function() {
        this.realModel.set(this.model.attributes);
    }
});
```

You could also do something a bit different:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // save the attributes up front, removing references
        this._modelAttributes = _.extend({}, this.model.attributes);
    },
    onSave: function() {
        // revert to initial state.
        this.model.set(this._modelAttributes);
    }
});
```

Comment: is `this.realModel.set(this.model.attributes);` definitely safe? I'm just thinking `this` values might be different (although I think `this` refers to `Backbone.Model` in both, I'm not sure)

Comment: Also, sorry for my ignorance, but what is the point of the line `var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});` - I don't see you using `Model` anywhere. Or were you just making an example and suggesting that you pass `Model` in as the model for view when you create an instance of it?

Comment: I was planning on initializing the view with a model, but I didn't. You can probably ignore the `var Model`. The `this` is `this.realModel.set(this.model.attributes)` refers to the view always since that is the current context.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Backbone.Memento](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.memento) a try.

If you don't want to use it no problem. But, You can get a good idea about how it should be done from the codebase.

Comment: is there a reason to use this over kalley's method above, or are you just providing an alternative?

Comment: No, It's an alternative. It is very small and provide bunch of other features. That's why I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this issue with an object cache on the view. That way I don't add any unnecessary overhead to model/view management. Discarding happens naturally if the user closes out of a view without saving.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    'title': 'Hello'
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {

        // Holds temporary values until save
        this.cache = {};

    },
    onTitle: function() {
        this.cache.title = 'World';
    },
    onSave: function() {
       this.model.set( this.cache );
    }
});
```