# Best Practice for changing the model of a Marionette.ItemView

Tags: model, marionette

In my application I have a CollectionView with an ItemView next to it (they're both visible at the same time). When an item is clicked in the list, the ItemView displays its details.

The easy solution is to trigger

```
bigLayout.itemDetailsRegion.show(new ItemDetailsView({
   model: modelOfClickedItem
});
```

But this makes the ItemView instance that was previously rendered to be closed and garbage-collected while a new instance of the same class is being created and rendered in the same place. To me and my team this smells as bad practice (deleting and re-creating a view seems to us useless overhead), but are we right?

At the time being, we added a changeModel(model) method to the ItemView class that

- unbinds events to the previous model
- assigns the new model to the view
- re-renders the view
- binds new events to the model

But we are not really satisfied (many times switching a model is more complex than that and this solution is not very scalable).

Is there something we could call "best practice" for this kind of need? Is the standard way (as described above) a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I don see why your first approach would be bad. It's nearly the same as you're doing manually using your changeModel method.

I suppose the most 'expensive' action is to re-render the view (DOM Manipulation) which is what you'll have to do regardless.

Another method I can think of is (using http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/):

```
// Create a stickit marionette itemView
var stickitItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    bindings: {},
    render: function(){
        // Invoke original render function
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
        var result = Marionette.ItemView.prototype.render.apply(this, args);

        // Apply stickit
        this.stickit();

        // Return render result
        return result;
    }
});

/* Setup a temp model in an itemView.
 * Several ways to do this, either define all attributes again or 
 * clone an existing model for example. In this case I assume you only want to display 
 * data from the model. If you want to modify it as well you'll have to keep a reference.
 * See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517028/how-to-clone-models-in-backbone
/*
var viewInstance = new stickitItemView({
    model: realModel.clone(),
    template: someTemplate,
    bindings: {
        '.some-element': 'attribute1',
        '.another-element': 'attribute2'
    }
});

// Show the view
someRegion.show(viewInstance);

// Use a another model to update the temp model's attributes. 
viewInstance.model.set(anotherRealModel.toJSON());
```

If I'm correct this is quite scalable, updates your DOM supposedly faster (test it!) and takes care of data-binding.

Comment: you confirm our suspect that DOM redrawing is the most expensive operation, actually. I like your answer (not enough reputation to give +1, sorry... :)

Comment: You're welcome! As I pointed out already, libraries like stickIt may be lighter with regards to the DOM manipulation part. Let us know what you end up using :)

Comment: Added a small example